# "D’où y sort ce pignouf ?" pourquoi le y ?

Tags: registre-familier, y

Le lemme de [Wiktionnaire](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/pignouf) pour le mot pignouf comporte l'exemple

> D’où y sort ce pignouf ?

Je me demande pourquoi le y à  cette tournure.

Comment: Ce ne doit pas être un il ? Je pense que sinon c'est tiré d'une certaine région en France comme dans le nord mais je ne suis pas sûr de mes propos

Answer (score 12, accepted):

En français parlé, le *L* du pronom *il* a tendance à ne plus être prononcé devant une consonne.

> Il est là : /i.lɛ.la/

> Il sort : /i.sɔʁ/

Pour rendre cette prononciation à l'écrit, on utilise souvent ***y*** comme dans la phrase citée, cette lettre ayant le mérite de déjà exister en tant que pronom et présentant une meilleure lisibilité comparée à un ***i*** simple.

Comment: En France, entends-tu parfois /iɛ.la/ et considères-tu ça comme plus basilectal ou du même niveau ?

Comment: @20goto10 Oui, on peut entendre /iɛ.la/ mais aussi /lɛ.la/. Il me semble que ces variantes sont moins systématiques que la chute du *L* devant une consonne qui est assez généralisée dans la langue spontanée.

Comment: Thanks. Je pensais à il->y mais je n'en étais pas sûr à cause de deux sujets : il sort et ce pignouf.

Comment: Tu aurais probablement mieux compris le soutenu: *D'où sort ce malappris ?*

Comment: _Cest bien là l'endroit d'où y sort le pignouf ?_  ahahhah

Comment: Dans le même genre : régionalement, on trouve "J'y ai dit" pour "Je lui ai dit"

Comment: @qoba Oui, le *L* disparaît aussi avec une étape intermédiaire *j'ui ai dit*.

Answer (score 4):

Ce que l'on doit trouver à la place de « y », c'est normalement « il ». Comment dans le français relâché la prononciation de « il » est « i », qui est la même que celle de « y » dans le texte, « y » est utilisé pour représenter le son de « i ».

Il ne semble pas y avoir de raison particulière pour choisir « y » plutôt que « i » ([Y, Wikipédia](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Y_(lettre)#Phon%C3%A9tique_et_phonologie)).

> Pour retranscrire la prononciation informelle des pronoms « il » et « ils », c'est-à-dire /i/ sans la.consonne finale, on utilise parfois « y » :
>
> « Y va bien. » au lieu de « Il va bien. »
> « Y vont bien. » au lieu de « Ils vont bien. »

[TLFi, **B Rem**](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/il)

> 4. La forme pop. [de « il »] est y ou i.
>    Ça va-t-y? V'là Andoche... C'est-i' jà l'angélu? (Martin du G., Gonfle, 1928, I, 1, p. 1171).

Comment: Je pense qu'on peut attribuer l'orthographe *y* au fait que *y* est aussi un mot courant, contrairement à *i*.

Comment: @qoba Je ne peux pas l'affirmer et vous non plus probablement mais ça m'a l'air d'une bonne idée ; je me demande comment on pourrait s'y prendre pour essayer de prouver ça.

Comment: B. − [Y désigne un référent autre que lui-même, directement, p. attrib. arbitraire, ou indirectement, en tant qu'abrév. d'un signe lex.] — https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/y